# how to hide all the toolbar of a ckeditor in c#

Tags: javascript, c#, ckeditor

this is the assmbly in the top of the page:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="CKEditor.NET" Namespace="CKEditor.NET" TagPrefix="CKEditor" %>
```

this is the:

```
   <CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="CKEditor1" BasePath="/ckeditor/" runat="server" EditingBlock="true" toolbar="emptyToolbar" ></CKEditor:CKEditorControl>
```

here is the config.js:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function (config) {
    // Define changes to default configuration here.
    // For complete reference see:
    // http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config

    // The toolbar groups arrangement, optimized for a single toolbar row.
    config.toolbarGroups = [
        { name: 'document', groups: ['mode', 'document', 'doctools'] },
        { name: 'clipboard', groups: ['clipboard', 'undo'] },
        { name: 'editing', groups: ['find', 'selection', 'spellchecker'] },
        { name: 'forms' },
        { name: 'basicstyles', groups: ['basicstyles', 'cleanup'] },
        { name: 'paragraph', groups: ['list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi'] },
        { name: 'links' },
        { name: 'insert' },
        { name: 'styles' },
        { name: 'colors' },
        { name: 'tools' },
        { name: 'others' },
        { name: 'about' }
    ];

    // The default plugins included in the basic setup define some buttons that
    // are not needed in a basic editor. They are removed here.
    config.removeButtons = 'Cut,Copy,Paste,Undo,Redo,Anchor,Underline,Strike,Subscript,Superscript';

    // Dialog windows are also simplified.
    config.removeDialogTabs = 'link:advanced';



};
```

what should i do??

how to disable all the toolbar??
how to hide all the toolbar of a ckeditor..I want only textarea of a ck editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this this line in to config.js file

```
config.removePlugins= 'toolbar';
```

**Updated**

Using css

```
   <head>
     <style> 
        .cke_top { display: none !important } 
     </style> 
   </head>
```

Comment: any other solution?

Comment: BOLD,I,?.:. ALL THESE THINGS ARE SHOW..SO how to hide??

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://jsfiddle.net/oleq/tjbjrowm/) it's done a trick using css is that fine or you want to hide it using js only?

Comment: i am not understand..can you write down here

Comment: you just have to add css style like this  .cke_top { display: none !important }

Comment: where should i write??

Comment: @mmmmm that's totally your call to how to make it work as fiddle works perfectly.